# What is the difference between square bracket arrays and pointer arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

As a non-C/C++ expert I always considered square brackets and pointers arrays as equal.

ie :

```
char *my_array_star;
char my_array_square[];
```

But I noticed that when use in a structure/class they don't behave the same :

```
typedef struct {
   char whatever;
   char *my_array_star;
} my_struct_star;

typedef struct {
   char whatever;
   char my_array_square[];
} my_struct_square;
```

The line below displays 16, `whatever` takes 1 byte, `my_array_pointer` takes 8 bytes. 
Due to the padding the total structure size is 16.

```
printf("my_struct_star: %li\n",sizeof(my_struct_star));
```

The line below displays 1, `whatever` takes 1 byte, `my_array_pointer` isn't taken in account.

```
printf("my_struct_square: %li\n",sizeof(my_struct_square));
```

By playing around I noticed that square brackets are used as extra space in the structure

```
my_struct_square  *i=malloc(2);

i->whatever='A';
i->my_array_square[0]='B';
```

the line blow displays A:

```
printf("i[0]=%c\n",((char*)i)[0]);
```

the line blow displays B:

```
printf("i[1]=%c\n",((char*)i)[1]);
```

So I cannot say anymore that square brackets are equals to pointers. But I'd like to understand the reason of that behavior. I'm afraid of missing a key concept of that languages.

Comment: In C you cannot declare `something[]` and must define the size of the array. Chose between the two.

Comment: @Eregrith: you *can* declare such an array at the end of a struct, and that is why it compiles.

Comment: I would stick to using the pointer for dynamically created arrays and not worry about it. I do not like that other syntax, seems abusive to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Arrays and pointers don't behave the same because they're *not* the same at all, it just seems that way.

Arrays are a group of contiguous items while a pointer is ... well ... a pointer to a *single* item.

That single item being pointed to may well be the first in an array so that you can access the others as well, but the pointer itself neither knows nor cares about that.

The reason that arrays and pointers often seem to be identical is that, in many cases, an array will decay to a pointer to the first element of that array.

One of the places this happens is in function calls. When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer. That's why things like the size of an array don't pass through to the function explicitly. By that I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void fn (char plugh[]) {
    printf ("size = %d\n", sizeof(plugh)); // will give char* size (4 for me).
}

int main (void) {
    char xyzzy[10];
    printf ("size = %d\n", sizeof(xyzzy)); // will give 10.
    fn (xyzzy);

    return 0;
}
```

The other thing you'll find is that, while you can `plugh++` and `plugh--` to your hearts content (as long as you don't dereference outside of the array), you can't do that with the array `xyzzy`.

In your two structures, there's a major difference. In the pointer version, you have a fixed size pointer *inside* the structure, which will point to an item *outside* of the structure.

That's why it takes up space - your 8-byte pointer is aligned to an 8-byte boundary as follows:

```
+----------------+
| 1 char variable|
+----------------+
| 7 char padding |
+----------------+
| 8 char pointer |
+----------------+
```

With the "unbounded" array, you have it *inside* the structure and you can make it as big as you want - you just have to allocate enough memory when you create the variable. By default (ie, according to the `sizeof`), the size is zero:

```
+----------------+
| 1 char variable|
+----------------+
| 0 char array   |
+----------------+
```

But you can allocate more space, for example:

```
typedef struct {
   char whatever;
   char my_array_square[];
} my_struct_square;

my_struct_square twisty = malloc (sizeof (my_struct_square) + 10);
```

gives you a variable `twisty` which has a `whatever` character and an array of ten characters called `my_array_square`.

These unbounded arrays can only appear at the end of a structure and there can be only one (otherwise the compiler would have no idea where these variable length section began and ended) and they're specifically to allow arbitrarily sized arrays at the end of structures.

Comment: Thank you for this top quality answer, congrats!

Comment: +1 excellent explanation.  I'm not sure if unsized member arrays are even allowed in the standards.  I usually get a warning about using a non-standard extension if I do this.

Comment: "Arrays decay to simple pointers when passed to a function": that's the reason I always prefer using pointer syntax in function arguments `void fn (char *foobar)` over array syntax `void fn (char foobar[])`

Answer (score 5):

The `my_array_square` member is what is called a "flexible" array member. Such arrays without a specified size can only appear at the end of a struct, and they don't contribute to its size. The intent is to manually allocate the rest of the space for as much elements as you need. Otherwise, the size of the array is determined at compile-time.

The usage pattern of such a struct would be as follows:

```
my_struct_square *s = malloc(sizeof(my_struct_square) + 5 * sizeof(char));
...
s->my_array_square[4]; // the last element of the array
```

In all other cases, the size of an array must be known at compile-time. Even the type of an array goes together with its size, i.e., `int a[20]` is of type `int[20]`, not just `int[]`.

Also, understanding the difference between arrays and pointers is crucial. @paxdiablo has covered that quite well.

Comment: Note that flexible array members are only allowed in C language version C99 or later. If code like this is attempted in C90 ("ANSI C") then I believe you can end up with crashes when writing data to the possible padding bytes that may be stored at the end of the struct, if the data written is a "trap representation". Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Lunding: I guess it shouldn't compile at all with a C90 compiler.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Not in all other cases must the array size be known at compile time since C99 introduced variable length arrays.