# Initializing structure array inside a structure array

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have a question in initializing my structure array inside a structure array. for example if I have a code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} FIRST_T;

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    FIRST_T *p;
} SECOND_T;

FIRST_T p1[]={{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
FIRST_T p2[]={{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

SECOND_T my_second[]=
{
{1,2,3,p1},
{4,5,6,p2}
};

}
```

if I have to initialize my first array in second array intialization part itself, then how would I write my typedef of SECOND_T?
like

```
SECOND_T my_second[]=
{
{1,2,3,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}},
{4,5,6,{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}}}
};
```

then how should be my SECOND_T?

I am sure I can't define it as:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    FIRST_T p[]; //(I know its a blunder)
} SECOND_T;
```

Please help.

Comment: I am not getting your question perhaps if you are saying that you want to initialize a array inside another structure array that will not be possible.
array has containing a address via that we can access element and you are initializing a array
inside another so how first array element will access through second element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a type with unbounded array in C, you have to specify the dimension. So you either do:

```
typedef strut {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    FIRST_T f[SOME_VALUE];
} SECOND_T;
```

and then initialize `SOME_VALUE` count of members **always**, or do it the way you did.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but it's perfectly legal (since C99) to have flexible array members, so your comment is wrong

Comment: @hroptatyr I believe you're wrong. You can declare unbounded array, but you cannot define its value in the way the OP wants. The default size of the unbounded array is 0, so you have to allocate memory before actually using it. I believe this question is of relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324995/what-is-the-difference-between-square-bracket-arrays-and-pointer-arrays

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, i.e, initialize the `FIRST_T` inside the initialization of `SECOND_T`, other than the first way you do it. Think about it, how can the compiler tell how many `FIRST_T` are there in `SECOND_T`? The problem here is, you can **NOT define an array of flexible size struct statically**.

Answer (score 0):

you can't to do like that:

```
SECOND_T my_second[]=
{
{1,2,3,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}},
{4,5,6,{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}}}
};
```

with

```
typedef struct {
int x;
int y;
int z;
FIRST_T p[]; //(I know its a blunder)
```

} SECOND_T;

becase the compiler don't know how to malloc memory for this struct. if you must do like this, you should define

```
typedef struct { int x,y,z; FIRST_T p[CONST_VALUE];}SECOND_T;
```

but I advise you use the first style that you write.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely capture the question that you have. If it is that you want to avoid to have to declare an auxiliary variable for the pointers in the structure you can use a compound literal as follows:

```
SECOND_T my_second[] = {
  {1,2,3, &(FIRST_T){{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}}},
  {4,5,6, &(FIRST_T){{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}}
};
```

You'd have a compiler that complies to C99 for that.