# Dynamic string array allocation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to allocate a dynamic string array in the following way and I get an error:

```
struct Test
{
    std::string producer[];
    std::string golden[];
};

Test test1 =
{
        {"producer1", "producer2"} ,
        {"golden1"  , "golden2"}
};
```

The error i get is that there are too many initializers for `std::string[0]`, 
but if I get off the array part it works:

```
struct Test
{
    std::string producer;
    std::string golden;
};

Test test1 =
{
        "producer1" ,
        "golden1"
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::string producer[];` You cannot declare an array without saying how many elements is should contain.

Comment: @Bo you can, but you cannot define it, you have to do it dynamically.

Comment: @littleadv Yes, but a non-static member declaration is a definition, and requires the size.  And you can't dynamically allocate any thing that has been declared.  To dynamically allocate a `string[]`, you'd have to define the object as a `string*`, not a `string[]`.  The only places where and actual `string[]` would be legal is as an `extern`, or as a reference parameter to a function (but that's a bit tricky, since you cannot then pass the function an array whose size is known).

Comment: @James, i won't explain it in the comment, but you're wrong. Note that he's defining a type here.

Comment: @littleadv Exactly.  He's defining a class, and non-static data member
declarations in a class are defintions, and require the size, see
§9.2/10 ("Non-static data members shall not have incomplete types.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize zero-sized arrays this way, because you have to **dynamically** allocate the memory. You can only do what you do if you specify the dimensions in the type definition.

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834897/initializing-structure-array-inside-a-structure-array/9835009#9835009).

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++11 **uniform initialization**:

```
struct Test
{
    vector<string> producer;
    vector<string> golden;  
};

Test test1 =
{
    {"producer1", "producer2"},
    {"golden1", "golden2"}
};
```

The following sample code compiles fine with g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    vector<string> producer;
    vector<string> golden;  
};


ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Test & test)
{
    os << "------------------------" << endl;
    os << "producer={" << endl;
    for (auto& p : test.producer)
    {
        os << '\t' << p << endl;
    }
    os << "}" << endl;

    os << "golden={" << endl;
    for (auto& p : test.golden)
    {
        os << '\t' << p << endl;
    }
    os << "}";
    os << "------------------------" << endl;

    return os;   
}



int main()
{
    Test test1 =
    {
         {"producer1", "producer2"},
         {"golden1", "golden2"}
    };

    cout << test1 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```